# Is an undeclared variable a reference to a function in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the `readRequest` in this Python code.

```
sc, sockname = s.accept()
    ...
requestType = data['RequestType']
print '[-] Type of data:',type(data)
print '[-] Data:',data
if requestType == 1:
    sc.sendall(readRequest)
```

`readRequest` looks like a variable, but if I do a search on readRequest I only find a method called readRequest, like this

```
def readRequest(path):
```

I don't see a variable called readRequest.

What is happening in this Python code? Is readRequest some kind of short hand for calling the readRequest method? If so, what parameter is getting passed?

I am looking through code I found. Is it possible that the code just has a bug or is incomplete?

Comment: As a really nitpicky note: that's almost certainly not a method, but a function. When you define a function as part of a class, that's a method. (And when you define a function as part of a class, nearly always, either it has an extra `self` first parameter, or it's decorated by `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you've found a bug, or you're wrong about what `readRequest` is.

It's perfectly valid to pass a function as an argument to another function (see, e.g., the [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function, which expects a function for its first argument).

But `sc` variable is almost certainly a [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), given that it comes from `sc, sockname = s.accept`, which means that [`sc.sendall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) is a function that takes a string of bytes and sends those bytes to the client on the other end of the socket. A function is not a string of bytes, so you will get an error that looks something like this:

```
TypeError: 'function' does not support the buffer interface
```

If that happens, most likely whoever wrote this code intended to *call* `readRequest` and pass its result, not just pass the function itself, in which case you'd fix it with:

```
sc.sendall(readRequest())
```

If, on the other hand, there's no error, that means `readRequest` isn't a function after all, but a string, and you just failed to find it in a search.